# error Arabic sentence for words are reversed on datatables pdfhtml5 with laravel8

Tags: laravel-8, pdfmake

[this example for error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSv6X.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEvgi.png)   'customize' =>"function(doc) {

```
                                        margin: [ 0, 0, 0, 5 ],
                                       } );
                              }",
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by using this code example

```
text:'الخير صباح'.split(' ').reverse().join(' '),
```